# How are T4 and NuGet related?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, t4

Many posts I read point out that both T4 and NuGet packages automate the creation of base code and it is something worth learning how to do.  So I am preparing to learn T4 coding first, after which I will undertake to learn NuGet.

As I do this, I am curious if there are important relationships between T4 and NuGet packages.  I see some posts that make references to both, but since I'm not yet able to do either, I don't understand the points being made.

How do T4 and NuGet interact?  Is it better to learn one first to make the other easier to learn?

Comment: [T4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019) and [NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget) are not related. They do not interact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GSerg pointed out, they are completely unrelated. To expand a little...

T4 is a templating system, meaning you can add a `.tt` file to your project, and it will generate files for you. These are likely to be code files (such as `.cs` files and so on), but don't have to be. T4 can generate any text files you like.

Nuget is a platform for allowing you to add packages to your project. Say you want to use Entity Framework, you add the appropriate package(s). Want some other library? Add the packages. Nuget is not at all about code generation, it's about adding pre-existing packages.

Hope that clarifies.

Comment: This was an old post, but I appreciate the response helping to confirm things for me.  I was able to work with templating files, but I only understand how to modify the ones that default load.  I'd like to understand how to do more useful manipulation of .tt files.  How to add them to the VS dialogues for greater variety in templating, but finding documentation has proved difficult.  If you have some links or suggestions to learn more, would appreciate it.

Comment: Regarding NuGet, I'd also like to learn how to do NuGet packages.  Do you have any links or guidance for tutorials from simple leading to complex projects?

Comment: @Alan For T4 files, the best resource I found was the book "Metaprogramming in .NET" by Hazzard and Bock. Only one chapter covers T4, but it's very clear and easy to follow. I struggled a lot with T4 before reading that. As for Nuget, there are no end of resources online. Search for "create nuget package visual studio" and you'll find plenty. This is a lot more complex though, so you'll need a lot of patience.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind help.  Best Regards,